# HTML - Strange issue with div boxes disappearing in Safari on scroll

Tags: html, css, safari

I have been making some modifications to an existing website and a strange issue seems to have arisen. After scrolling down, and then back up, some div elements on the page are disappearing. The problem only seems to appear when using Safari on a desktop.  Moving the mouse seems to cause the divs to immediately reappear...

Our jQuery uses some 'on scroll' triggers but these have never caused any of the problems that appear now, and I suspect that this is not the cause of this strange problem.

The problem on the page can be viewed here http://www.upreach.org.uk/2014/about.php

I've never experienced a problem like this and am quite perplexed about what could be causing it.

Comment: I trying this on Windows with Safari, I can't reproduce that bug.

Comment: Why are you using img with position fixed to do a fixed background ? I guess Safari can make the z-index flicker and go above all in some case. You can try put .wrapper-holder a big z-index (i.e. 9999) to fix it.

Comment: Hi @enguerranws thanks for this.  I'm using Safari on a mac, so it could be a mac-specific bug...?

Comment: I guess. I'll post some fixes as answers.

Comment: Thank you!  I also changed z-index:9999; but that doesn't seem to fix the problem.  All seems quite strange to me...  Will await your suggestions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some fixes you can try :

- give to the .shell element a big z-index and be sure it always has a position relative (not right now):

  .shell { 
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative !important;
    z-index: 9999;
  }
- if you can, don't put your background as an image with a fixed position, it occurs some bugs in some browsers, do the same with :

  body { background-attachment : fixed; }

(Yeah, you'll need to put your background image in the body).

Comment: Thanks so much for your help @enguerranws - this seems to have fixed the problem!

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty logical : your .shell element has no position set, so the z-index property is useless. The strange thing is the fact that it's working on the other browsers :) You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case somebody else is having this specific issue in the same way I was. Check if you are using transform-style: preserve-3d. That was the problem for safari in the wrapping divs of my virtual scroll.